# Сравнение значений id и itemId каждого элемента двух списков

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть два списка: `List<Item> items и List<Opt> opts (opts.size() >= items.size()` всегда).

```
public class Item {
...
private Long id;
private Sring name;
...
// sets and gets
}

public class Opt {
...
private Long itemId;
private String itemName;
...
// sets and gets
}
```

Нужно сравнивать `item.id` и `opt.itemId` каждого из элементов и если `id.equals(itemId)`, то установить `opt.setItemName(item.getName());`

Моя фантазия дошла только до вложенных друг в друга

```
forEach ((

    opts.forEach(opt -> items.forEach(item -> {
        if (opt.getItemId().equals(item.getId())) {
            opt.setItemName(item.getName());
        }
    }));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, это можно сделать как-то лучше ?

Comment: Может лучше использовать SortedSet?

Comment: Если бы две коллекции всегда были одного размера, то тогда да. Отсортировать items по id, а opt по itemId и просто по индексам присваивать, но они могут быть разными.

Comment: Тут зависит от задачи. Я думаю можно сделать так: Вам нужен SortedSet<Item>, отсортированный по id. И List<Opt>. Проходим for-ом по всем элементам List<Opt> и для каждого ищем в SortedSet<Item> элемент с таким же id, если находим, то присваиваем. Поиск по дереву будет намного производительней чем сравнение каждого с каждым через вложенные циклы.

Comment: Еще больше под вашу задачу подходит Map для хранение пар типа Long и String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать предварительную обработку и сложить все элементы из какой нибудь коллекции в хэш таблицу. А после интерируюсь по другой коллекции, доставать список этих элементов с одинаковыми идентификаторами.

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Opt> opts = new ArrayList<>();

Map<Long, List<Opt>> optMap = opts
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Opt::getItemId));
itemList
            .forEach(item -> 
                    optMap
                            .getOrDefault(item.getId(), Collections.emptyList())
                            .forEach(opt -> opt.setItemName(item.getName())));
```

По сравнению с первоначальным вариантом, где сложность была квадратичная `O(N*M)`, этот алгоритм работает за `O(N+2M)`